# Is there a way to start always as a root?

Tags: debian, users, login, root, startx

I'm using **Debian** *Wheezy*, and I need to be always as a root. So I do the following every-time I restart the OS: `$ sudo -i` then `startx`.

Is there a way to restart directly as **a root every-time**?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using GNOME if you're on Debian :

edit /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

You should get something like this :

```
[daemon]
# Enabling automatic login
  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
  AutomaticLogin = root
```

You could replace root by an other user

More info here : https://wiki.debian.org/GDM

Small note : Loggin as root is not a good practice, depending on what you need, you could simply use the commande sudo to gain permission for a moment
In gnome, loggin in the GUI as root is disable by default (Considered unsafe)

EDIT : 
To bypass that protection, you could go in GNOME's setting, under Security and check Allow to login as Root

Cheers.

Comment: I did what you recommended, but now it gives me the login window to choose a user. I have only my user and when I choose *other* and type in the username as "root" and the corresponding password, it gives me "authentication failed"

Comment: Try to go in gnome settings, in Security, you should be able to check something like Allow root/admin to log in.